# Creating multiple vertices in JanusGraph with single query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I am programming (in Java) to insert a large volume of vertices and edges into JanusGraph. Using the standard gremlin queries, I could not find any API that allows me to insert multiple edges/vertices in one go. I finally used addV and addE in a loop . Is there any API that would allow me to bulk add vertices/edges (either the gremlin way or a Janusgraph specific way ..both are fine)

Comment: Finally, this is what I did : I used JanusGraph java API to add vertices and edges in batches of 25K per transaction. This was a good boost to the performance

Answer (score 3):

You can chain multiple addV and addE steps together in a single query such as:

```
g.addV('person').as('p1').
  addV('person').as('p2').
  addE('knows').from('p1').to('p2')
```

You could have maybe one or two hundred like that in each query you send.